# How to use selenium3 in jmeter webdriver Sampler

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I use JMeter4 + Selenium2 + Firefox 45 in webdriver sampler to test GUI. This works well, but if we want to test the new version of Firefox (for example, version 55), we need to install Selenium 3. The JMeter webdriver plugin (version 2.3) requires Selenium 2.

How can I make webdriver sampler + selenium 3 work in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

You will not able to use current WebDriver Sampler version with Selenium 3.x as it relies on some [Selenium API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) which has incompatible changes, even if you upgrade Selenium libraries the WebDriver Sampler will not work.

However you can try the following approach:

1. Uninstall WebDriver Sampler and all its dependencies (or even better obtain a fresh copy of JMeter)
2. Download Selenium 3 client .jar(s) and put them into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Write your Selenium-related code using [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) or [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler

You can also reach out WebDriver Sampler plugin developers/maintainers and clarify when/if support of newer Selenium version will be added at [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins)

Comment: you are right! I have tried jmeter beanshell + selenium3,it works. but what is the difference bewteen use beanshell and JSR223? i am a beginner in jmeter and selenium:)

Comment: Given you use Groovy language in JSR223 sampler you will have more modern language features as Beanshell supports Java 5 syntax. Moreover, when it comes to high loads Beanshell performance can be a big question mark. More information: [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)